# Selectpicker after rendering

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

i use Knockout, and my issue is that it seems i cannot render the Selectpicker. I will jump right into some code, to help myself explain.

Scripts:

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>


<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-select.min.css">
```

here is the script i need to render the dropdown box.

```
$(document).load(function () {
    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker({
        liveSearch: true,
        showSubtext: true
    });

});
```

Here is the Ajax i use to get my objects and bind them to the View.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:  "@Url.Action("GetView", "Medarbejders", new {area = "" , id = ViewBag.id})",
        }).done(function (data) {
            $(data).each(function (index, element) {
                var mappedItem =
                    {
                        Id: ko.observable(element.Id),
                        MedarbejderId: ko.observable(element.MedarbejderId),
                        Mode: ko.observable("edit")
                    };
                console.log(mappedItem);
                viewModel.lookupCollection.push(mappedItem);
            });



            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            // Here is where i think i would need to Render the script. But getting an Error see futher down.

        });
    });
```

Which brings me to my Template.

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: lookupCollection">

        <tr data-bind="template: { name: Mode, data: $data }"></tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="display">






    <td data-bind="text: MedarbejderId"></td>


    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-success kout-edit">ændre</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger kout-delete">slet</button>
    </td>


</script>

<script type="text/html" id="edit">



    <td><u>Medarbejder</u><br />@Html.DropDownList("MedarbejderId", (SelectList)ViewBag.MedarbejderId, "Vælg medarbejdere", htmlAttributes: new
                           {
                               @data_bind = "value: MedarbejderId",
                               @class = "selectpicker form-control",
                               data_show_subtext = "true",
                               data_live_search = "true"

                           })
    </td>
```

if i inspect my page using developer tool, i get the Error in the console ".selectpicker is not a function in jquery" Can somebody help me out? been sitting with this error Last couple of days.

When putting the render script in, this is the error i get.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function
```

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7RDc3/5854/

If you add a newline the selectpicker doesn't work.

Comment: are you using bootstrap picker?

Comment: Yes, bootstrap-select.

Comment: did you tried reordering js reference?

Comment: Yes, sadly no luck.

Comment: can you show me the bundling you did?

Comment: only have theese 2 in my layout. 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
Should mention, that it works on my other pages where i do not use Knockout.

Comment: Okay, I have not gotten the Selectpicker to work, Used the online scripts from https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/9abm0hhy/ instead, but i cannot open the dropdown using my mouse, only search by writing something.

Comment: I see you only have bootstrap-select.min.js but not bootstrap.js itself?

Comment: it's bundled in, i have now made a JSfiddle. as you can see selectpicker works but if i make a new line it doesn't will add it to the subject aswell.

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7RDc3/

Comment: Sorry i forgot to update the fiddle. Here new link: http://jsfiddle.net/7RDc3/5854/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to inside you `addGifts` function:

```
self.addGift = function() {
    self.gifts.push({
        name: "",
        price: ""
    });
    $(".selectpicker:visible").selectpicker({
        liveSearch: true,
        showSubtext: true
    });
};
```

The `$(".selectpicker:visible")` will only initialise the select pickers that have not been initialised ie. visible.

Working Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7RDc3/5855/

Comment: Haha Thanks, you wont believe how long i spend finding this solution. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same iusse a few month ago. For the problem was that the site wasn't loading the js files correct. These are the things i tried and one of this solved my problem.

1. If you use your layout on this site too, remove: 
   `<script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>` casue you're
   already adding jquery to your layout with
   `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`
2. Instead of adding your js files like `<script src="~/scripts/filename.js"></script>` add them to your *BundleConfig* like this: `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/path-to-your-js/jsname.js"));` and use them like: 
   `@section Scripts{ @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jsbundlename") <script type="type= text/javascript"> //js-code</script>}`
3. Do the same for your css files but like this: `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css";` and use them like this: `@section Styles{ @Styles.Render("~/bundles/cssbundlename")}`

Comment: Thanks for your Respond, But in this case it wont change anything, since the Selectpicker is working in a standalone. It's only when i add new objects it doesn't. But i will change it up for bundles again. Thanks.